# how to search through a public email archive?

Tags: email, search, archive

Email lists keep their emails in archives. Sometimes I want to search through those archive but I don't know how to do it. Of course I can open it one by one (actually month by month) and search the content, but it's nonsense to do that.  This afternoon I read the README file for u-boot. IT says :

```
Where to get help:
==================

In case you have questions about, problems with or contributions for
U-Boot, you should send a message to the U-Boot mailing list at
<u-boot@lists.denx.de>. There is also an archive of previous traffic
on the mailing list - please search the archive before asking FAQ's.
Please see https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot and
https://marc.info/?l=u-boot
```

But when I see https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot, it's just emails archived by the past months. How can I search through them? For example if I want to search through, say, "lan9220"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some list archives have integrated search functions, the second one you mentioned has it: https://marc.info/?l=u-boot&w=2&r=1&s=lan9220&q=b but the easiest way would IMHO be google: `"lan9220" site:https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/`

You could also download the compressed archives for every month, these contain just a single text file so it should be quite easy to create a script to download and extract all of them and then use grep to search through them, but it sounds like overkill -- I would just use google.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But how did you find the integrated search function? (https://marc.info/?l=u-boot&w=2&r=1&s=lan9220&q=b) I need this kind of search function for some other email archives.

Comment: Go to https://marc.info/?l=u-boot and notice the search box at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Some mailing-list archives provide their own search functions, but for those that don’t, you can use your favourite search engine, by specifying your search terms and the archive’s URL prefixed with `site:`. Thus, with DuckDuckGo, https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lan9220+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Flists.denx.de%2Fpipermail%2Fu-boot%2F

Alternatively, you can download all the archive files, import them into a mailbox indexer such as [notmuch](https://notmuchmail.org/).